# How do you find a missing number in a table field starting from a parameter and incrementing sequentially?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sequence

Let's say I have an sql server table:

NumberTaken   CompanyName

2                      Fred
  3                      Fred
  4                      Fred
  6                      Fred
  7                      Fred
   8                      Fred
   11                    Fred

I need an efficient way to pass in a parameter [StartingNumber] and to count from [StartingNumber] sequentially until I find a number that is missing.

For example notice that 1, 5, 9 and 10 are missing from the table.

If I supplied the parameter [StartingNumber] = 1, it would check to see if 1 exists, if it does it would check to see if 2 exists and so on and so forth so 1 would be returned here.

If [StartNumber] = 6 the function would return 9.

In c# pseudo code it would basically be:

```
int ctr = [StartingNumber]
while([SELECT NumberTaken FROM tblNumbers Where NumberTaken = ctr] != null)    
    ctr++;

return ctr;
```

The problem with that code is that is seems really inefficient if there are thousands of numbers in the table. Also, I can write it in c# code or in a stored procedure whichever is more efficient.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called my table Blank, and used the following:

```
declare @StartOffset int = 2
; With Missing as (
    select @StartOffset as N where not exists(select * from Blank where ID = @StartOffset)
), Sequence as (
    select @StartOffset as N from Blank where ID = @StartOffset
    union all
    select b.ID from Blank b inner join Sequence s on b.ID = s.N + 1
)
select COALESCE((select N from Missing),(select MAX(N)+1 from Sequence))
```

You basically have two cases - either your starting value is missing (so the Missing CTE will contain one row), or it's present, so you count forwards using a recursive CTE (Sequence), and take the max from that and add 1

*Edit* from comment. Yes, create another CTE at the top that has your filter criteria, then use that in the rest of the query:

```
declare @StartOffset int = 2
; With BlankFilters as (
    select ID from Blank where hasEntered <> 1
), Missing as (
    select @StartOffset as N where not exists(select * from BlankFilters where ID = @StartOffset)
), Sequence as (
    select @StartOffset as N from BlankFilters where ID = @StartOffset
    union all
    select b.ID from BlankFilters b inner join Sequence s on b.ID = s.N + 1
)
select COALESCE((select N from Missing),(select MAX(N)+1 from Sequence))
```

this may now return a row that does exist in the table, but hasEntered=1

Tables:

```
create table Blank (
    ID int not null,
    Name varchar(20) not null
)
insert into Blank(ID,Name)
select 2 ,'Fred' union all
select 3 ,'Fred' union all
select 4 ,'Fred' union all
select 6  ,'Fred' union all
select 7 ,'Fred' union all
select 8 ,'Fred' union all
select 11 ,'Fred'
go
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer I tried to close the duplicate but it wouldn't let me. I have just one more question, let's say I want to filter the table before querying it, for example, if 'Blank' had an extra field 'hasEntered' and I want to run your query on only the fields that 'hasEntered' <> 1, is it possible to do that without making a temp table?

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `JOIN`:

```
select min(r1.NumberTaken) + 1
from MyTable r1
left outer join MyTable r2 on r2.NumberTaken = r1.NumberTaken + 1
where r1.NumberTaken >= 1 --your starting number
    and r2.NumberTaken is null
```

Comment: Ok I have a little problem, I've need it to count from 1 and onwards so for example if the table above was missing the first row Numbertaken[1] it needs to return 1. Any ideas?

Comment: Use union instead of r1, like (select numbertaken from r1 union 0) as x or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try the set based approach - should be faster

```
select min(t1.NumberTaken)+1 as "min_missing" from t t1
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 
                   where t1.NumberTaken = t2.NumberTaken+1)
and t1.NumberTaken > @StartingNumber
```

This is Sybase syntax, so massage for SQL server consumption if needed.

Comment: I changed the query to SELECT q.NumberTake + 1 FROM [QUEUE] q
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT q2.NumberTake FROM [QUEUE] q2 
WHERE q2.NumberTake = q.NumberTake + 1 )I have a little problem, I've need it to count from 1 and onwards so for example if the table above was missing the first row Numbertaken[1] it needs to return 1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp table with all numbers from StartingValue to EndValue and LEFT OUTER JOIN to your data table.