# How do you find a missing number in a table field starting from a parameter and incrementing sequentially?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

Let's say I have an sql server table:

NumberTaken   CompanyName

2                      Fred
  3                      Fred
  4                      Fred
  6                      Fred
  7                      Fred
   8                      Fred
   11                    Fred

I need an efficient way to pass in a parameter [StartingNumber] and to count from [StartingNumber] sequentially until I find a number that is missing.

For example notice that 1, 5, 9 and 10 are missing from the table.

If I supplied the parameter [StartingNumber] = 1, it would check to see if 1 exists, if it does it would check to see if 2 exists and so on and so forth so 1 would be returned here.

If [StartNumber] = 6 the function would return 9.

In c# pseudo code it would basically be:

```
int ctr = [StartingNumber]
while([SELECT NumberTaken FROM tblNumbers Where NumberTaken = ctr] != null)    
    ctr++;

return ctr;
```

The problem with that code is that is seems really inefficient if there are thousands of numbers in the table. Also, I can write it in c# code or in a stored procedure whichever is more efficient.

Thanks for the help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you find a missing number in a table field starting from a parameter and incrementing sequentially?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025341/how-do-you-find-a-missing-number-in-a-table-field-starting-from-a-parameter-and-i)

Comment: @Damien - I'd say exact duplicate

Comment: @El Ronnoco - that comment's auto generated when I close as "Exact duplicate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine, if this question isn't going to be closed, I may as well Copy and paste my answer from the other one:

I called my table Blank, and used the following:

```
declare @StartOffset int = 2
; With Missing as (
    select @StartOffset as N where not exists(select * from Blank where ID = @StartOffset)
), Sequence as (
    select @StartOffset as N from Blank where ID = @StartOffset
    union all
    select b.ID from Blank b inner join Sequence s on b.ID = s.N + 1
)
select COALESCE((select N from Missing),(select MAX(N)+1 from Sequence))
```

You basically have two cases - either your starting value is missing (so the Missing CTE will contain one row), or it's present, so you count forwards using a recursive CTE (Sequence), and take the max from that and add 1

Tables:

```
create table Blank (
    ID int not null,
    Name varchar(20) not null
)
insert into Blank(ID,Name)
select 2 ,'Fred' union all
select 3 ,'Fred' union all
select 4 ,'Fred' union all
select 6  ,'Fred' union all
select 7 ,'Fred' union all
select 8 ,'Fred' union all
select 11 ,'Fred'
go
```

Comment: @Andomar - because normally closes happen fairly quickly, but the additional votes don't seem to be coming in. In the meantime, the answers that are appearing are, shall we say, not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a temp table containing all numbers from StartingNumber to EndNumber and LEFT JOIN to it to receive the list of rows not contained in the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

If NumberTaken is indexed you could do it with a join on the same table:

```
select T.NumberTaken -1 as MISSING_NUMBER 
from myTable  T
left outer join myTable T1
on T.NumberTaken= T1.NumberTaken+1
where T1.NumberTaken is null and t.NumberTaken >= STARTING_NUMBER
order by T.NumberTaken
```

**EDIT**

Edited to get 1 too

Comment: It wouldn't return '1', the first missing number

Comment: it now won't work for 12. In general, you won't be able to get one end of the sequence or the other if you're trying this kind of trick.

Comment: So what if '2' is missing. I need it to start from 1 check to see if the record exists, if so return if not increment by one. If '2' would be missing as well it needs to return 1 because 1 is the first number missing. If '2' is missing '1' should be returned your code returns '2'

Comment: @Damien-The-Unbeliever That's true; however i thought it just need to get the hole in the sequence. If you also need the last number you can always get the max if the query return an empty data set.

Answer (score 0):

```
1> select 1+ID as ID from #b as b 
   where not exists (select 1 from #b where ID = 1+b.ID)
2> go
 ID         
 -----------
           5
           9
          12
```

Take max(1+ID) and/or add your starting value to the where clause, depending on what you actually want.